# VPN Auto for Subnet Access in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

While implementing VPN Access in softlayer, I don't understand what Auto mode is in Subnet Access.
Is there API to implement Auto mode ? 
I do understand Manual mode, but confuse how it works in auto mode.
Please refer to the attached png file.

[image: VPN Access]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto mode will grant to your user permissions to all subnets in your account, so once he connects to the VPN he will able to interact with the devices through remote desktop (RDP) via SSH and KVM over IP. 
Using manual you can restrict the access to the subnets .

In order to enable manual configuration you only have to change the user property " "vpnManualConfig" see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_User_Customer

Also see:
http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/topic/vpn

Comment: Thanks..  In case of auto mode, Override.createObject() should be implemented for all subnets ?

Comment: nope, in auto mode you do not need to createObjects, softlayer automatically allows the access.

Comment: I think "customer.vpnManualConfig" should be true or false depending on Autoaccess mode.  thanks